# Redirecting Users to a mobile version of a static site using WURFL

Tags: php, mobile

Would I simply us the capability filter and have it return the devices capabilities, and then based off of the capabilities, write an if else statement that will either redirect the user to the mobile or the desktop version of my site based off of devices? Basically how do I implement WURFL into my website, I am reading the documentation and the configuration information is all there but there is no clear solution for my problem, I am fairly new to all of this, so this is likely a very basic question. Thanks

Comment: can I write an if istable or if isphone statement that redirects users to the mobile site

Comment: You are correct with your initial assumption.  What language is your website built in and which WURFL API are you using?